# How to instantiate a record that has a only a single field in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

If the record has more than one field this works:

```
type record_one_field_t is record
    abit : bit;
    abit2 : bit;
end record;
constant record_one_field : record_one_field_t := ('0', '1');
```

but if there is a single field:

```
type record_one_field_t is record
    abit : bit;
end record;
constant record_one_field : record_one_field_t := ('0');
```

GHDL 0.34 gives:

```
can't match character literal '0' with type record type "record_one_field_t"
```

I think this is because `('0')` is being lexed as a character.

Why I want to do this instead of just using a `bit` variable:

- I am starting a design, these are the inputs, and I think I will add more inputs later
- curiosity

Comment: Named association.  `t := (abit => '0');`

Comment: @BrianDrummond will you answer and get rep or shall I? :-)

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.1 (Record Aggregates) para 4 *"Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions."*  Not as a character, as a parenthesized expression. And yes, '0' is not of a record type. You'd get the same message for the character literal without parentheses, the message is ambiguous, demonstrable with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of 8 lines.

Comment: @user1155120 put that standard quote in an answer and get my upvote.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of research, particularly if you'd accept a quote from the standard as an answer. You could also use `constant record_one_field : record_one_field_t :=  (others => '0');` See 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.1 General, 9.3.3.2 Record aggregates: "If the choice **others** is given as a choice of a record aggregate, it shall represent at least one element." And about here I'd note you declare an object of a type, not instantiate it. 6.4.2 Object declarations, 6.4.2.2 Constant declarations.

Comment: @user1155120 I give great importance to standards, and I should have found this one by myself, but google -> stack overflow gives answers faster for most people. Standards don't always give understandable answers if you're not familiar with them (but this quote was very clear). If you don't answer, I will :-)

Comment: I wouldn't use Stackoverflow as a primary reference, the quality isn't there. Answer away (noting that Brian's answer is particularly accurate sans authoritative references).

Comment: @user1155120 OK! I agree it should not be authoritative, but it is a good way to quickly find the authoritative one, and sometimes it's interpretation if needed. Just making it a bit faster for the next person ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Named association.

`constant record_one_field : t := (abit => '0');`

Normally you can use either named or positional association, but for a record or array with only one component, only named association works, because positional would be ambiguous, exactly as you suspected.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 1076-2008 9.3.3.1 (Record Aggregates) explicitly says that it is not possible and that you need to use named association as mentioned by Brian Drummond:

> Aggregates containing a single element association shall always be specified using named association in order to distinguish them from parenthesized expressions.

Mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924463/how-to-instantiate-a-record-that-has-a-only-a-single-field-in-vhdl?noredirect=1#comment63307316_37924463).